# Java plugin loaded through URLClassLoader not returning after run

Tags: java, multithreading, plugins

**BLUF**: When I run one of my custom plugins, execution does not return back to the parent until the plugin is complete.

**Background**:
I have a parent/plugin setup where the each plugin implements a basic interface

```
public interface PluginInterface {
    public int load(String configFile);
    public boolean run();
    public boolean stop();
    public boolean unload(boolean now);
}
```

I load the plugin from the parent app using URLClassLoader.newInstance().  Once it is loaded, I call the plugin interface function load() and pass the configuration file.  All good up to this point.

Inside the plugin, run() is implemented as such

```
@Override
public boolean run() {

    if (_pbs == null)
        return false;

    //ThreadStart just implements Runnable and does the actual work
    _ts = new ThreadStart(_pbs);
    _ts.run();

    return true;
}
```

Essentially I create a new thread to do the actual execution so that run() can return back to the parent and it can continue to execute.  This doesn't happen though.  Execution after calling run() from the parent doesn't occur until the plugin has finished doing its work.  So my question is, what am I doing wrong and why does the parent hang until the plugin is totally done?  They are not short lived tasks either so I would expect that the plugin thread would be suspended at some point and a context switch occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `_ts.start();` or `new Thread(_ts).start();`

Comment: Jeez.  That simple.  Thanks.